# Avoid Do you want to save changes you have made

Tags: oracleforms

I have created a form in Oracle Forms 10g and have a view-based block with custom filter so when I put some text in filter textbox and press button, block should be filtered. That works fine but I get message I want to avoid: Do you want to save changes you have made. Data block is Database block and I think the problem is filtering it, using filter is reduced and this change cause a message.
How could I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: set the filter item to Database Item = No, or move it to a control block.

Comment: Hi GriffeyDOg, thanks for replying. The filter is custom filter, not oracle's one. I have few text items and button. On button pressed I have set_block_property('db_block', default_where, par_default_where);
 execute_query; db_block is view based block.

Answer (score 0):

For the Filter Item Do the following changes to the properties

```
DatabaseItem-->No
UpdateAllowed-->No
```